How to get specific edger voucher data with date range?
I have created a simple .NET application to connect with Tally Prime. I am using tally connector package in the application.
I am able to the make call to APIs like getting company names, list of ledgers. Now I am trying to get ledger Voucher Report for specific ledger name with from and to date, which will return the voucher number, voucher type, opening, closing balance the same way it shows in tally prime.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.
I tried calling GetVoucherAsync API, but I'm always getting no records, although there are records when I click on ledger Voucher in tally prime for that ledger with the date range.
VoucherRequestOptions voucherRequestOptions = new VoucherRequestOptions()
{     
FromDate = new DateTime(2023,1,1),     
ToDate = new DateTime(2024, 1, 1),     
Company = "Company Name" 
};

var voucher = tallyService.GetVoucherAsync(ledgerName, voucherRequestOptions ).Result;

var vouchers=tallyService.GetVouchersAsync(voucherRequestOptions).Result; 
foreach (var v in vouchers) 
{     
Console.WriteLine($"Voucher Number: 
{v.VoucherNumber}, Date: {v.Date}"); 
}

Not sure is this a correct way to get specific ledger voucher data with date range.

Is the Date in voucher a string or a DateTime object.  You may need to convert the DateTime to a string using FromDate = new DateTime(2023,1,1).ToString("M/d/yyyy")

@jdweng no need to convert to string tally connector supports datetime object and conversion to tally formats is handled by library

Hi @saivineeth, is this only way to get ledger Voucher or their is other apis to get this data.Is there any reference that I can follow to get such data.

in case you missed it I added link to voucher tests where I covered some ways using same method

In v3, I am planning to add new api, GetVouchersBasedonLedgerName, GetVouchersBasedonStockitemName etc.,

you can refer voucher tests on how to query vouchers
you can only pass lookup options like masterid,guid,voucher number only when using GetVoucherAsync method and it will return only one voucher
if you want to get multiple vouchers based on ledger then

 var vchs = await _tallyService.GetVouchersAsync<Voucher>(new RequestOptions()
 {
     FromDate = new(2023, 1, 1),
     Filters = new List<Filter>() { new("TCLedgerFilter", "$$FilterCount:AllLedgerEntries:TCLedgerInternalFilter > 0"), new("TCLedgerInternalFilter", $"$LedgerName = \"{ledgerName}\"") { ExcludeinCollection=true} },

 });



you can pass any filters that tally supports

Thanks @saivineeth for the information, I will try this.
